# IDENTITY vs SEQUENCE OBJECT IN SQLSERVER

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm moving my configuration tables from *Development* environment to *Test* environment.

I'm using `Identity` as a primary key for the configuration tables.

Identity has option `SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TABLE_NAME] [ON|OFF]` that lets you insert values in the Identity column.

Here is an example for the same:

```
CREATE TABLE test_Identity (
    [ID] int Identity (1,1),
    [Product Name] nvarchar(50)
)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT test_Identity ON

INSERT test_Identity ([ID], [Product Name]) VALUES (1,'PRODUCT1')

SET IDENTITY_INSERT #test_Identity OFF
```

The above code lets me insert values specific values in the Identity column.

Now is there a way to insert specific values while using a `SEQUENCE OBJECT` in SQL Server?

Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent to `identity_insert` for sequences. Just insert the desired values normally.

A sequence is just tied to a column with a default constraint and supplies a default value if you don't override it.

There is nothing special about a column with a sequence default it is treated the same as any other column and can have explicit values inserted or be updated.